# How to open conemu form current folder?

Tags: console, shortcut, conemu

I used cmder that can open console from current folder thought windows shortcut menu by clicking mouse right key.
You can add shortcut of cmder to right-click menu by

> cmder /regesiter

But when using conemu, I can't find way to open console form current folder.

Is there some way I can do it?

thanks a lot

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. Cmder.exe is not ConEmu.exe. So, what exactly do you try to do?

Comment: Sorry, I fault. I want to say when I use Cmder.exe I can open console at current folder, but when I use ConEmu.exe I can't do it. Is there some ways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find the approach: Settings -> Integration -> ConEmu Here -> Register